# Can I close connection established by different process

Tags: python, sockets, networking, websocket, connection

I stuck with program which have to show information about all local addresses and remote addresses, PID, and also to disconnect by demand exact established connection. So, I guess it should be like netscan. Is it possible to close port (and disconnect) without process killing?

```
import os
import socket
import re
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_DGRAM
import serial
import psutil as psutil

AD = "-"
AF_INET6 = getattr(socket, 'AF_INET6', object())
proto_map = {
    (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM): 'tcp',
    (AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM): 'tcp6',
    (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM): 'udp',
    (AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM): 'udp6',
}


def main():
    templ = "%-5s %-30s %-30s %-13s %-6s %s"
    print(templ % (
        "Proto", "Local address", "Remote address", "Status", "PID",
        "Program name"))
    proc_names = {}
    for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
        proc_names[p.info['pid']] = p.info['name']

    for c in psutil.net_connections(kind='inet'):
        laddr = "%s:%s" % (c.laddr)
        raddr = ""
        if c.raddr:
            raddr = "%s:%s" % (c.raddr)
        print(templ % (
            proto_map[(c.family, c.type)],
            laddr,
            raddr or AD,
            c.status,
            c.pid or AD,
            proc_names.get(c.pid, '?')[:15],
        ))


def closeConn(ip):
    print("///////////////////////////////////////////////")
    print("Trying to close connection:", ip)
    print("///////////////////////////////////////////////")
    ser = serial.Serial()
    port = re.search(r":\d+", command).group(0)[1:]
    ser.port = port
    ser.close()
    main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    while True:
        command = input()
        if command == "quit":
            break
        if re.match(r"close", command):
            connToClose = re.search(r"[^a-z, ]+", command)
            if connToClose:
                closeConn(connToClose.group(0))
            else:
                print("IP or Host cannot be empty... Enter new command. Example >>> close 192.168.0.1")
        else:
            print("Please enter valid command...")
```

I tried to solve this problem with serial, but as I understand, serial is new isolated object and its `close` method has influence right on this object. So is there any way to close existing connections?

Comment: Your question starts off about "connections" with "local and remote addresses".  Then you show a program that dumps inet connections *and* interacts with a serial port.  What do serial ports and inet connections have to do with each other?  The question is confusing.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone question is it starts about. I guess this snippet shows what data is displayed in console. So I want to interact with that data, I mean to be able close established (as declared in received data) connections.I couldn't do it neigther with "psutil" nor with "serial". I don't know what serial is and for. It just my assumption to use it.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone As example I get "tcp - 127.0.0.1:5434 - 63.156.00.12 - firefox". as a string in list showed by this program. I want to close this connection without killing firefox. At least disconnect 63.156.00.12. To perfectly close 5434 port

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any Python library to close an arbitrary TCP connection with a local endpoint.  However, there are programs with this functionality - for example, tcpkill (part of dsniff) and ss (part of iproute2).  You can run these with any of Python's libraries for running child processes.